# Azure Stream Analytics job not detecting input stream from Event Hubs

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to send streaming data from Event Hubs to Stream Analytics, but it is giving me the following error:

**Unable to connect to input source at the moment. Please check if the input source is available and if it has not hit connection limits. [SessionID: 7c4d6b29ff034f94b330590470ce2cfe]**

I tried changing different input settings and also tried troubleshooting through Microsoft documentation, but it is still giving me the same error every time.

Does anyone have any idea what's the solution to this?

Please note I'm using the basic tier (free version) of MS Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Few things I recommend checking are:

1. Authentication mode you are using to connect to input source. If you building a solution in dev/test environment, you can easily get started with connection string. If you plan on using Managed Identity as auth mode, you must ensure the job's identity has access to the input source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/event-hubs-managed-identity
2. If you are using Event Hubs as input, its recommended you configure use a separate consumer group for that streaming input in your Stream Analytics job: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshoot-input#job-exceeds-maximum-event-hub-receivers
3. Sometimes there could be transient errors which might cause this problem temporarily. Retrying after few minutes might help resolve this issue.